# Creating remote directories in a bash script via ssh (with error trapping)

Tags: bash, linux, ssh

I'd like to create directories on a remote VM, but only if they do not exist. What's more, if creating the directory results in an error (exit status != 0) I'd like the script to exit as well, or at least print an error. Is there a more succinct way to do this than what I have below?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, I want to `test -d` first so `mkdir -p` won't produce output about the directory already existing.

```
#!/bin/bash

mydirs=(/var/www/files /var/www/photos /var/www/info)
for d in ${mydirs[@]}; do
   ssh remotehost "test -d $d"
   res=$?
   test $res -ne 0 && { ssh remotehost "mkdir -p $d"; res=$?; }
   test $res -ne 0 && { echo "error during mkdir on remote"; exit 1; }
done
```

Comment: Normally you'd put the script on the server / VM itself, and run it after logging in through SSH. It would certainly be more efficient than running separate commands over SSH.

Comment: Thanks.This is part of a larger provisioning system which configures a VM into a specialized server. What I'm really wondering about is making it work with less code. Maybe what I have is about as trim as it gets.  I can do away with the `$res` variables but as far as I see, that's about it.  Just thought I'd try this forum before comitting the code in.

Comment: @ServerFault If you are designing a system for provisioning multiple VMs, consider using proper system administration tools such as Puppet or Ansible instead of rolling your own scripts.

Comment: @200_success Good reminder, but please stay on-topic. This question is about code review, not process review.

Answer (score 4):

Running `ssh` in a loop is not efficient. Since the script is not interactive,
you could pass the entire script to a remote Bash process on `stdin`,
so that loop will run entirely on the remote server, locally:

```
ssh remotehost bash << "EOF"
mydirs=(/var/www/files /var/www/photos /var/www/info)
for d in ${mydirs[@]}; do
   test -d $d
   res=$?
   test $res -ne 0 && { mkdir -p $d; res=$?; }
   test $res -ne 0 && { echo "error during mkdir on remote"; exit 1; }
done
EOF
```

Notice the double-quotes around the here document label, this is to avoid variable interpolation. The entire script is passed to the remote shell literally.

I made only the minimal changes to illustrate the point. Some important improvements are well advised:

- All variables used as command line arguments should be double-quoted: `"${mydirs[@]}"`, `"$d"`, and so on.
- As a comment mentioned, when using `mkdir -p`, it's unnecessary to test if the directory exists.
- Now that the main operations run in a single process, the pipeline can be simplified.
- As another comment mentioned, consider investing in learning a proper system administration tool such as Puppet, Ansible, Chef, or similar.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. I never thought about using ssh with a HERE doc

Answer (score 3):

Succinct:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
ssh remotehost mkdir -p /var/www/{files,photos,info}
```

Failure to create any directory will give non-zero exit for ssh, which causes the outer script to exit with error, because of the `-e` switch.

`mkdir` will print suitable error messages if it encounters errors.   If you prefer the error message to appear on standard output (like `echo` would do), you can redirect standard error (aka "filehandle 2") to stdout (filehandle 1) by appending `2>&1`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
ssh remotehost mkdir -p /var/www/{files,photos,info} 2>&1
```

Comment: Trading some succinctness for a little extra efficiency, we could prefix the command with `exec` since there's no need to return to the shell.

Comment: There's a slight difference IIUC: the original stops at the first error, but `mkdir` will continue with subsequent arguments before exiting with a failure code.

Comment: @TobySpeight good point and that makes `-e` unnecessary so it's only 2 extra characters.

Comment: This is a great way to shorten it up but how do I get the `test -d` in there so no output (`File exists`) is produced if `mkdir -p` fails?

Comment: `mkdir -p` does not print "file exists" if the file exists.  It does nothing.